# How can I make apache redirect to www subdomain?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, dns

I have the following in `sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywrk
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
   <Directory "/var/www/html/mywrk">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
         Require all granted
  </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Here it's working but mydomain.com (without www) does not redirect to www.mydomain.com

In the apache2 host, how can I set non-www to redirect to www? I mean mydomain.com should redirect to www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check the module rewrite this enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

2) In the main configuration of Apache you must have something like this enabled:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
<Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

Note the this line: ***AllowOverride All***

3) Then, drop the following into a file called .htaccess in you root directory server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```